# PHP simple_html_dom and file_get_html in foreach loop. How to speed up parse time?

Tags: php, sockets, loops, foreach, simple-html-dom

I'm using PHP simple_html_dom and file_get_html in a foreach loop which loops about 4,000 times.

Here's what I'm doing. I'm extracting content from multiple urls on same host.

There are 4,000+ urls all on the same host. `example.com`

Example url: `example.com/product.php?prod=00283`

On the next pass-thru of the loop `example.com/product.php?prod=03418`

next pass-thru of loop `example.com/product.php?prod=08192`

etc, etc until all 4000+ urls are looped over.

Tested 100 urls took over 1 and a half minutes to parse and output content.

**Is it possible to setup a multithreaded approach in the foreach loop to bring back the contents of all 4000 urls simultaneously?**

**In other words, do I use sockets or some other kind of multithreaded approach to iterate over all the urls in parallel?**

Here is my sample code below so you can see what I'm doing here.

```
include 'simple_html_dom.php';

$partlist_file = 'parts.txt';

$partlist = file('partnumberlist.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);

$stock = '';

    $isFirst = true;
    $firstline = 'sku,qty,visibility,is_in_stock' . "\n";
    $output_first = '';
    foreach($partlist as $parts => $part) {

        $html = file_get_html('example.com/product.php?prod=' . $part);
        $ret = $html->find('span#cph_lb_stock_buy'); 

        foreach($ret as $element) {
            $stock = $element->plaintext;
            $stock = preg_replace(array('/\\n/','/\\r/'),'',$stock);
            $stock = trim($stock);
            if($stock == 'Not in stock.') {
                $stock = '0,1,0';
            } elseif($stock == 'In Stock & Ready to Ship!') {
                $stock = '4,4,4';
            }

        if ($isFirst) {
          $output = $firstline;
          $isFirst = false;
        }

        $output .= 'K' . $part . ',' . $stock . "\n";


        }
    }
    //print_r (trim($output,"\n"));
    file_put_contents($partlist_file, trim($output,"\n"));
```

Comment: i think that preg_replace do nothing but take many time

Comment: and firstline you can output before loop then check condition every time

Comment: @splash58 I did what you said, but parsing time is same.

Comment: is it possible to setup sockets in a foreach to bring back the contents of all 4000 urls simultaneously?

Comment: There is a difference between parse time (CPU) and network latency so you need to decide which is your issue. Also PHP may not be the best choice if you decide you need a multithreaded solution.